# Best practice : get deep value of an object

Tags: java

Often in java I have to get a value of a property of an object which is deep in this object. For example, if I'm sure that all my sub-objects are not null, I can do that :

```
public function getDeepValue(A a) {

    String value = a.getB().getC().getListeD().get(0).getE().getValue();
    return value;
}
```

But in case of sub objects of the parent can be null, I have to test every object.
To do that, I see 2/3 solutions :

First, step by step :

```
public function getDeepValue(A a) {

    if(a == null){
        return null;
    }

    B b = a.getB();
    if(b == null) {
        return null;
    }

    C c = b.getC();
    if(c == null){
        return null;
    }

    List<D> ds = c.getListeD();
    if(ds == null || ds.size() == 0){
        return null;
    }

    D d = ds.get(0);
    if(d == null) {
        return null;
    }

    E e = d.getE()
    if(e == null){
        return null;
    }

    return e.getValue();
}
```

Second, test all in one if block, soooo dirty :

```
public function getDeepValue(A a) {

    if(a != null && a.getB() != null && a.getB().getC() != null && a.getB().getC().getListeD() != null && a.getB().getC().getListeD().size() > 0 && a.getB().getC().getListeD().get(0) != null && a.getB().getC().getListeD().get(0).getE() != null){
        return a.getB().getC().getListeD().get(0).getE().getValue();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Third solution, using a try catch block :

```
public function getDeepValue(A a) {

    try {
        return a.getB().getC().getListeD().get(0).getE().getValue();

    } catch(NullPointerException e) {
        return null;

    } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Solution 1 seems not too bad but needs a lot of code. It is generally the solution I use.
Solution 2 is for me really dirty...
In paper, I realy like solution 3, but is it a good solution in term of performances ?

Is there any others acceptables solutions ?
Thanks for help, I hope my english is not too bad..
Regards

Comment: Relevant read: "law of demeter" (for example this one: http://www.ccs.neu.edu/research/demeter/demeter-method/LawOfDemeter/paper-boy/demeter.pdf)

Comment: Best practice would be to refactor so you don't have to go through a big chain of possibly-null values. Out of the three solutions presented, I like the third one the least. You'll notice that it also catches exceptions that could be from within the get methods and transforms this into a null return value.

Answer (score 1):

Solution #3 looks simple, but it can potentially hide a whole host of problems. It *might* be an adequate solution if you have full access to all of the classes in the chain and you know what's going on in each method and you can guarantee those methods won't cause problems with your try/catch and you're never going to change them... that's a lot of conditions to make it a worthwhile solution, but I can conceive that it's possibly a <s>useful</s> sufficient one.

Solution #2 looks horrid to me, especially if one or more of the `get` methods is a bottleneck (such as a slow database query or using a blocking network connection). The earlier in the chain such a potential bottleneck, the worse it would potentially be, as you're calling it over and over again. This of course depends on the implementation of the methods in question (even if one of them is slow, the result could be cached, for example), but you shouldn't *need* to know that in your client code. Even with efficient or trivial implementations, you've still got the overhead of repeated method calls you oughtn't need.

Solution #1 is the best of the three, but it's likely not the best *possible*. This solution takes more lines of code than the other two, but it doesn't repeat itself and it isn't going to be tripped up by the implementations of the other methods. (Note: If you do not have access to the classes in the chain for refactoring, I would use this solution.)

A better solution than #1 would be to refactor the classes so that the client code doesn't need to know about this chain *at all*. Something along these lines:

```
class Client {
    public Mumble getDeepValue(A a) { return a == null ? null : a.getDeepValue(); }
}

class A {
    private B b;
    public Mumble getDeepValue() { return b == null ? null : b.getDeepValue(); }
}

class B {
    private C c;
    public Mumble getDeepValue() { return c == null ? null : c.getDeepValue(); }
}

class C {
    private List<D> ds;
    public Mumble getDeepValue() {
        D d = ds == null || ds.size() == 0 ? null : ds.get(0);
        return d == null ? null : d.getDeepValue();
    }
}

class D {
    private E e;
    public Mumble getDeepValue() { return e == null ? null : e.getMumble(); }
}

class E {
    private Mumble m;
    public Mumble getMumble() { return m; }
}
```

As you can see, the longest chain any of these classes has is to access the public members of an element of a collection that is a private member of the class. (Essentially `ds.get(0).getDeepValue()`) The client code doesn't know how deep the rabbit hole goes, only that `A` exposes a method which returns a `Mumble`. `Client` doesn't even need to know that the classes `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, or `List` exist anywhere!

Additionally, if I were designing this system from the ground up, I would take a good long look at whether it could be restructured such that the actual `Mumble` object wasn't so deep. If I could reasonably get away with storing the `Mumble` within `A` or `B`, I'd recommend doing it. Depending on the application, that may not be possible however.

Comment: Also this decouples the source and the caller so if the deep value is moved to a different location they'll be few changes needed to be made to the source code.

Answer (score -1):

in terms of performance solution 3 is the best one. In addition It is neat and easy to understand , For example looking at a loop example:

```
int[] b = somevalue;
for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++){
  //do something
}
```

in this case for every iteration we execute the condition. However, there is another approach for it which uses try and catch

```
int[] b = somevalue;
try{
  for(int i=0;;i++){
    //do something
  }
}catch(IndexOutOfBoundException e){
  // do something
}
```

on the second solution,the loop keeps going until we reach the end of the loop which then it throws `IndexOutOfBoundException` as soon as we reach the end of the array. meaning we don't check for the condition no more. thus faster.